# How to test Firebase Deep Linking?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, firebase-invites

So I added a test Firebase deep link, how can I test if this works? I added the SHA-1 for both debug and release keys etc.

Then after install If I give this command:

```
$ adb shell am start
    -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW
    -d "http://myurl.com" com.mypackage
```

My intent gets started, then in this part:

```
AppInvite.AppInviteApi
        .getInvitation(googleApiService.getmGoogleApiClient(), (Activity)getContext(), true)
        .setResultCallback((result) -> {
            Log.d(TAG, result.getStatus().toString());
            if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                // Extract deep link from Intent
                Intent intent = result.getInvitationIntent();
                String deepLink = AppInviteReferral.getDeepLink(intent);
                Log.d(TAG, "Deep link: "+deepLink);
            }
        });
```

it says that

```
Status{statusCode=CANCELED, resolution=null}
```

In the Firebase console I see "Short Dynamic Link" and "Long Dynamic Link". Should I test with those?